# curses.addstr does not output to console

Tags: python, windows, curses, python-curses

I've recently installed the `windows-curses` module on my machine, via `py -m pip install windows-curses` run in an elevated command prompt.

I wrote the following code to test if it was working correctly. If it runs correctly, it should print the string `test` to the console. However, nothing happens - i.e the terminal remains blank, with no characters displayed.

```py
#initialise curses
import curses
stdscr=curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
stdscr.keypad(True)

#write text
stdscr.addstr(0,0,'test')

#loop program so the terminal does not close
while 1:
    pass
```

I've tried putting the `addstr` call inside the while loop, as well as using the `wrapper`, but neither resolved the issue.
What's going on, and how can I resolve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to refresh the screen. Curses does a physical screen update when you ask for input, e.g. with `window.getch()` or call `window.refresh()` directly.
Try this snippet:

```
#write text
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'test')

#loop program so the terminal does not close
while 1:
    c = stdscr.getch()
    key = curses.keyname(c)
    if key == b'q':
        break
    else:
        stdscr.addstr(1, 0, repr(key))

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Thanks. `window.refresh` was exactly what I was looking for.